# How did these websites see through the VPN tunnel?

Tags: privacy, vpn

I'm using [privateineternetaccess](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/how-it-works/) to VPN my internet connection. Recently I've noticed some web sites appear to know my real location and IP address. The most alarming incident I've seem to have been resolved but I don't understand why it happened and was hopping someone could shed some light.

I had just cleared my browser cache. I went to the page http://whatismyipaddress.com/ and it was showing my real location (though not my real IP address, at least according to `ipconfig`) even though VPN was working. I clicked on "update your IP location" and allowed my browser to share its location and then the map showed the location of the VPN server (which is expected). What I don't understand is how is this possible? I deleted cookies and everything so it couldn't have remembered a previous visit. Since the VPN service has shared IP addresses it couldn't have remembered the IP address. So even if I had visited the website a past time without VPN how would it know it is me again?

When creating a new Microsoft account the country I am in is automatically selected. How is this possible and how do I prevent it?

Under Google's recent activity it show's all sign in attempts from the actual geographical location my computer is at.

When I download a torrent from isohunt.com the torrent is downloaded from xx.isohunt.com where xx is the countries code (e.g. us)

Also hxxp://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/ redirects to a page where my country and language is listed in the URL.

I know some people recommend a script blocker. I'm hesitant to do this since many legitimate pages require scripts and as far as I'm aware scripts can't actually determine the real IP address or location (if someone can prove me wrong please do!). Is there a better solution to blocking all scripts, if that's even the problem?

Recently I got a new ISP that installed a wireless router. Could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: Anonymity is fraught with leaks, always...

Comment: To have any chance of keeping your connection leak-free, you must install a VM, firewall it such that only the VPN traffic goes out, have a fresh browser install in it and never input any login details created outside into it!

Comment: It sounds like your DNS or WebRTC is leaking, but I don't know enough about it to complete a satisfying answer. Some references  may help pinpoint if this is it: https://browserleaks.com/webrtc and https://www.dnsleaktest.com/  The other possibility took over a default route, but your eth0 or wireless connection kept a default route also after your VPN connects . This can lead to this sort of behavior if you have 2 defaults routes, as there should only be one.